# How to share behavior between methods

Tags: php, oop

I've a set of getter/setter methods to interact with my classes properties, here are two similar ones:

```
public function Criteres ($name = '',$value = false)
 {if ($name == '') return $this->Criteres;
  else if ($value !== false && strlen($name)) $this->Criteres[$name] = $value;
  else if (strlen($name)) return (isset($this->Criteres[$name]) ? $this->Criteres[$name] : '');}

public function Navigation ($name = '',$value = false)
 {if ($name == '') return $this->Navigation;
  else if ($value !== false && strlen($name)) $this->Navigation[$name] = $value;
  else if (strlen($name)) return (isset($this->Navigation[$name]) ? $this->Navigation[$name] : '');}
```

they have exactly the same behaviour, the only change is the property on which they act. I should mention that the properties being accessed are in fact **arrays containing several properties**

**is there a way to make them extend come kind of abstract METHOD which will make them act the same without defining the lines each time?**

or any other way then extending, I don't really care.

for exemple, the result I'd like is something along these lines:

ps. I **KNOW** this is not how we use abstract classes, *abstract* would be some kind of keyword to help php understand that the class defined is a template

```
abstract function setterGetter ($name = '',$value = false)
 {if ($name == '') return $this->{PROP};
  else if ($value !== false && strlen($name)) $this->{PROP}[$name] = $value;
  else if (strlen($name)) return (isset($this->{PROP}[$name]) ? $this->{PROP}[$name] : '');}
```

then, defining a custom setter/getter for a property:

```
public function Criteres extends setterGetter ({Criteres})
 {}
public function Navigation extends setterGetter ({Navigation})
 {} // without the need to define the code, they all act the same
```

Comment: You could always just define `__call($prop, $args){ if($args[0] == '') return $this->$prop; else if...`

Comment: No brackets ? *I wonder* what will happen if your indentation goes crazy

Comment: @AlexandruG. What do you mean? I usually master my indentation pretty well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not extend methods neither can you have an abstract method that is implemented by two different methods with distinct names. After all abstract classes as well as interfaces should provide a unique way to address functions.

But if both, `Criteres` and `Navigation` are methods/members of the same class, you can write a general setter/getter for those referenced objects. For example:

```
class MyData {

    protected $criteres;
    protected $navigation;

    public function objectHelper( $type, $name = null, $value = null )
    {
        $possibleTypes = array( 'Criteres', 'Navigation' );

        if( !in_array( $type, $possibleTypes ) )
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException( 'There is no such child object as ' . $type );
        }

        $type = strtolower( $type );

        if( empty( $name ) )
        {
            // getter
            return $this->$type;
        }
        elseif( !empty( $value ) )
        {
            /* setter
             * Attention: there no check at this point whether the key $name exists. */
            $this->$type[$name] = $value;
        }
        elseif( isset( $this->$type[$name] ) )
        {
            // specific getter
            return $this->$type[$name];
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * PHP magic function to use direct name notation
     *
     * Example:
     * 
     *   $myData->Navigation( 'name', 'value' );
     */
    public function __call( $prop, $args )
    {
        return $this->objectHelper(
            $prop,
            isset( $args[0] ) ? $args[0] : null,
            isset( $args[1] ) ? $args[1] : null
        );
    }

}
```

Hint: In PHP it is convention to use `null` for function arguments that are not required.

I would try to avoid mixing setters and getters altogether. Your code would be much more readable, testable and probably has more performance.

Comment: +1, and I wonder about mixing setter and getters. I've largely inspired myself from jQuery on this one

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Mixing setter and getter functions is used often in the [facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) which simplifies the API. But I recommend to use setter and getter functions for each class member. In your case, you can probably wrap the data checking into a helper function if it used often (more than three times).

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I've updated the answer to add an example for the [PHP magic method `__call`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods), as suggested by scragar in the comment above. You can now write your calls as desired, e.g. `$myData->Navigation( 'name', 'value' );`.

Comment: thx, I was rolling my own `__call()` tryout, and it definitely is more obscure then yours

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I use those magic functions primarily as convenience wrapper for existing functions, so they are mostly very short.